# Webscraping merriam-webster using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, lxml

I am using beautifulSoup and trying to scrape only the first definition (very cold) of a word from merriam-webster but it scrapes second line (a sentence) as well. This is my code. 
P.S: i want only the "very cold" part. "put on your jacket...." should not be included in the output. Please someone help.

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/freezing"

r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"lxml")

definition = soup.find("span", {"class" : "dt"})

tag = definition.findChild()

print(tag.text)
```

Comment: Just split the string.

Comment: I'm not a python or beautiful soup user, but it looks like you want to grab the first text node child of the definition span you are finding.

Answer (score 3):

Selecting by class is second faster method for css selector matching. Using select_one returns only first match and using next_sibling will take you to the node you want

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/freezing')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
print(soup.select_one('.mw_t_bc').next_sibling.strip())
```

Answer (score 2):

The way that Merriam-Webster structures their page is a little strange, but you can find the `<strong>` tag that precedes the definition, grab the next sibling and strip out all whitespace like this:

```
>>> tag.find('strong').next_sibling.strip()
u'very cold'
```

Comment: thank-you very much for the reply. You solved the problem.

Comment: @TaimoorIshtiaq excellent! consider accepting if this solved your problem! [When someone answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)